# Extending inherited properties c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, extends

I have a class that inherits from a base class

There are two further classes that have lists of these original classes as properties

I think the two new classes should have inheritance, but can't seem to get things to work.

```
public class Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public bool Standard { get; set; }
}

public class BaseAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public List<Attribute> AttributeList = new List<Attribute>
    {
        new Attribute {Name = "Hands", ShortName = "HA", Standard = true},
        new Attribute {Name = "Arms", ShortName = "AR", Standard = true},
    };
}

public class BaseProfile: Profile
{
    public List<BaseAttribute> AttributeList
    { get; set; }
}
```

Can I change the type of the inherited AttributeList to extend it to include the value property on each element?
Or should I not be inheriting at all in terms of the BaseProfile?

I've tried searching on here (and the wider interwebs), and there are a number of answers which help for simple inheritance, but I couldn't find one where the type of a property is changed during inheritance.

Comment: First off start favoring [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Second you can make `AttributeList` generic in your `Profile`-class.

Comment: You can´t change `AttributeList` to become a property in the derived class when it is a field in the base-class, unless you *hide* the base-implementation using the `new`-keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute is a bad name for the class, choose another name for it. (It's a standard .Net class and it's better to avoid using it even at the end of the classname, since ending with attribute implies that this class is inhereted from Attribute).

```
    public class Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public bool Standard { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profile<T> where T:Attribute,new ()
    {
        public List<T> AttributeList = new List<T>
        {
             new T {Name = "Hands", ShortName = "HA", Standard = true},
             new T {Name = "Arms", ShortName = "AR", Standard = true},
        };
    }

    public class BaseProfile : Profile<BaseAttribute>
    {

    }
```